# postgres timestamp with or without timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone

Being a postgres beginner , I was debating whether or not to define a timestamp field with or without timezone.

However, after looking at some docs, I came across this statement:

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

Which seems to be exactly what I want (utc, converted to timezone of client)

Would someone be able to tell me why anyone would want to store a timestamp *without* timezone info ?

For example, I was looking at the gitlab CE schema, and I see that they define all timestamps as without timezone

`created_at timestamp without time zone,`

So I tested this, and updated an issue in gitlab. The issue was updated at 18:55 (it's actually 19:55 in the UK) and a friend in Denmark sees the same time (18:55) even though it's 20:55 over there.

Surely it would be better to show times as a time-zone aware timestamp ? (ie he sees the issue as updated @ 20:55, I see it as 19:55)

I thought I had a handle on this, but if a big project like gitlab goes against what I thought was the appropriate use, one starts to question one's own judgement ;)

Comment: Let's say you run a restaurant chain and you have specials that run from 1200 to 1700 every day local time. Would you want to store that as timestamp with timezone, a different entry for each region, or just as a regular old timestamp? 

OTOH that gitlab example should be WITH time zone, IMHO.

Basically if the time needs to be coherent / relatively the same for everybody then you store it with time zone and adjust on delivery. If it needs to be the same time of day in each area, you don't.

Comment: I can see that - and also agree with you I think gitlab should be with TZ. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe - actually in that scenario one would use the `time [ without time zone ]` type.  :)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was getting at there. Thanks for clarifying.